# Stop content load after get xhtml with CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I'm doing a web scraping and to have a faster extraction of informations I need just the xhtml from a specific page.

By now, I'm using CefSharp to navigate to page, and after some user interact with the page (insert kind of login), my bot blocks the CefSharp controller and begins the info extract.

My problem is:
Using the "network" tab from DevTools on Google Chrome, I can see that the information I need (xhtml) is loaded in 400ms, but CefSharp waits all gifs and images load before continue the info extraction (that takes 1200ms).

I've tried to use DownloadHandler and LoadingStateChanges (the current extraction is made using FrameLoadEnd) but I don't know if it's the right way to do it.

I'm glad if someone brings a light to my newbie mind

Comment: I suggest you supply a minimal working example, so we can help you more specifically. Right now the question is too broad and lacks context https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For individual resource load notifications use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IResourceRequestHandler_OnResourceLoadComplete.htm There is a slightly different example that should give you a basic idea at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering

Comment: See also http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IResourceRequestHandler_OnBeforeResourceLoad.htm you can just cancel all sub resource requests.